# I'm having an Issue with a simple HTML/jQuery page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on this problem for 3 days, and I still have no answer to this problem I'm facing, it must be simple I just can't figure it out.

I'm using HTML and jQuery for a simple jQuery/HTML page to navigate 3 pages.

the problem is that when I swipe between pages I have kind of layout flash, for the first second after I swipe I see the page resizing and showing the first page for a flash second, and then the page would be normal again.

Here is my code :

[JS FIDDLE LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/genius50/L8vd5kxf/)

```js
var newsnum=10;
var i=1;
 $("body").on("swipeleft",function(){
 if (i<newsnum) {
   i++;
   $.mobile.changePage('#p'+i, {
      allowSamePageTransition :true,
            transition: "fade"});
   }});     
   $("body").on("swiperight",function(){
    if (i>1) {
      i--;
      $.mobile.changePage('#p'+i, {
        allowSamePageTransition :true,
        transition: "fade",
        reverse: true });
     }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="p1">

        <img style="width:800px; height:200px" src="http://www.parismania.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Didot_Matuidi.jpg" class="img-responsive" > <br><h4 align="left" style="color:#E49B0F; padding-left:10px;"> 111111111 </h4> <div> <h5 style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"> Touchée à la cheville droite la semaine passée, la milieu de terrain Sandie Toletti (Montpellier) ne sera pas opérationnelle pour la Coupe du Monde au Canada (6 juin au 5 juillet). C'est sa coéquipière au MHSC Marina Makanza qui la remplace.<br\/><br\/>Communiqué de la FFF\ <br\/>Dimanche 3 mai dernier, lors du match de D1 féminine entre Juvisy et Montpellier, Sandie Toletti s’est blessée à la cheville droite.<br\/> <br\/>Les staffs médicaux du HSC Montpellier et de l’Equipe de France féminine ont constaté son indisponibilité pour une longue durée. D’un commun accord, ils ont laissé la milieu de terrain à la disposition de son club.<br\/>Retenue parmi les sept réservistes pour la prochaine Coupe du Monde féminine (6 juin - 5 juillet au Canada), elle est remplacée par Marina Makanza (HSC Montpellier).<br\/> <br\/>À l’exception des joueuses du Paris SG, qui disputeront jeudi la finale de la Ligue des Champions, les Tricolores entameront demain (lundi) au Centre National du Football (CNF) à Clairefontaine (Yvelines) leur préparation pour la Coupe du Monde de la FIFA.
        
        Touchée à la cheville droite la semaine passée, la milieu de terrain Sandie Toletti (Montpellier) ne sera pas opérationnelle pour la Coupe du Monde au Canada (6 juin au 5 juillet). C'est sa coéquipière au MHSC Marina Makanza qui la remplace.<br\/><br\/>Communiqué de la FFF\ <br\/>Dimanche 3 mai dernier, lors du match de D1 féminine entre Juvisy et Montpellier, Sandie Toletti s’est blessée à la cheville droite.<br\/> <br\/>Les staffs médicaux du HSC Montpellier et de l’Equipe de France féminine ont constaté son indisponibilité pour une longue durée. D’un commun accord, ils ont laissé la milieu de terrain à la disposition de son club.<br\/>Retenue parmi les sept réservistes pour la prochaine Coupe du Monde féminine (6 juin - 5 juillet au Canada), elle est remplacée par Marina Makanza (HSC Montpellier).<br\/> <br\/>À l’exception des joueuses du Paris SG, qui disputeront jeudi la finale de la Ligue des Champions, les Tricolores entameront demain (lundi) au Centre National du Football (CNF) à Clairefontaine (Yvelines) leur préparation pour la Coupe du Monde de la FIFA.</h5></div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="p2">

        <img style="width:800px; height:200px" src="http://www.paris-saint-germain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/jalletcapitaine-480x280.jpg" class="img-responsive" > <br><h4 align="left" style="color:#E49B0F; padding-left:10px;"> 2222222222 </h4> <div> <h5 style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"> Touchée à la cheville droite la semaine passée, la milieu de terrain Sandie Toletti (Montpellier) ne sera pas opérationnelle pour la Coupe du Monde au Canada (6 juin au 5 juillet). C'est sa coéquipière au MHSC Marina Makanza qui la remplace.<br\/><br\/>Communiqué de la FFF\ <br\/>Dimanche 3 mai dernier, lors du match de D1 féminine entre Juvisy et Montpellier, Sandie Toletti s’est blessée à la cheville droite.<br\/> <br\/>Les staffs médicaux du HSC Montpellier et de l’Equipe de France féminine ont constaté son indisponibilité pour une longue durée.res entameront demain (lundi) au Centre National du Football (CNF) à Clairefontaine (Yvelines) leur préparation pour la Coupe du Monde de la FIFA.
        
        Touchée à la cheville droite la semaine passée, la milieu de terrain Sandie Toletti (Montpellier) ne sera pas opérationnelle pour la Coupe du Monde au Canada (6 juin au 5 juillet). C'est sa coéquipière au MHSC Marina Makanza qui la remplace.<br\/><br\/>Communiqué de la FFF\ <br\/>Dimanche 3 mai dernier, lors du match de D1 féminine entre Juvisy et Montpellier, Sandie Toletti s’est blessée à la cheville droite.<br\/> <br\/>Les staffs médicaux du HSC Montpellier et de l’Equipe de France féminine ont constaté son indisponibilité pour une longue durée. D’un commun accord, ils ont laissé la milieu de terrain à la disposition de son club.<br\/>Retenue parmi les sept réservistes pour la prochaine Coupe du Monde féminine (6 juin - 5 juillet au Canada), elle est remplacée par Marina Makanza (HSC Montpellier).<br\/> <br\/>À l’exception des joueuses du Paris SG, qui disputeront jeudi la finale de la Ligue des Champions, les Tricolores entameront demain (lundi) au Centre National du Football (CNF) à Clairefontaine (Yvelines) leur préparation pour la Coupe du Monde de la FIFA.</h5>
</div>

    
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="p3">

        <img style="width:800px; height:200px" src="http://img.modernghana.com/images/content/y17gx33wvr_191408935_15493.jpg" class="img-responsive" >   <br><h4 align="left" style="color:#E49B0F; padding-left:10px;"> 3333333333 </h4> <div> <h5 style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"> Dimitri Payet affichait un grand soulagement après la victoire de son équipe à l'arraché face à Monaco. Le meneur de jeu de l'OM a avoué qu'à un moment de la rencontre, il se demandait même comment Marseille pourrait ne serait-ce que prendre un point.<br\/><br\/>« Honnêtement, à un moment, on a senti que ça allait être très compliqué, même d’égaliser, avouait le meneur de jeu de l’OM Dimitri Payet sur Canal Plus après la victoire renversante de son équipe face à Monaco dimanche soir (2-1, 36eme journée de L1). Mais contrairement à d’autres matchs où on dominait et où on se faisait contrer à la fin, là, on n’a peut-être pas été beaux à voir jouer mais on a su être efficaces. On ne va pas faire la fine bouche, on va savourer, parce que si on n’avait pas gagné ce soir, on pouvait dire adieu au podium. Eux (les supporters), on n’a rien à leur reprocher. On dit que c’est un public difficile, mais, cette année, malgré beaucoup de faux-pas de notre part, ils ont toujours été là. Ce soir encore, c’était plein. Et quand ça pousse comme ça, ça donne de l’énergie. »\ <br\/>« On dépend encore de Monaco »\ <br\/>« Les changements ? C’est le coach, c’est lui qui décide, nous on essaye de s’adapter au mieux, poursuivait l’ancien Stéphanois. Il y a eu beaucoup de critiques sur ça. Ce soir, ça marche et ça paye. On va savourer car c’est une victoire très importante. Malheureusement, on n’a pas encore notre destin entre les mains, on dépend encore de Monaco. On revient à la hauteur de Saint-Etienne, les derniers matchs vont être très importants, ça va être chaud.</h5> </div>



</div>
```

Comment: on your fiddle I see it working properly. It looks like the normal fade effect.

Comment: Yeah but when you test it on mobile or any browser it doesn't work properly